# Javascript alert when user closes the tab ot the window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want when a user closes the tab or window or when he tries to move to another location different from my site to pops a confirm box, and if he confirm to execute an ajax script and then to close or change the window. I don't know how to do that. PS: I'm using jQuery.

Comment: Please stop asking duplicate questions. If you need to revise your question, simply edit it.

Comment: Also, would it kill you to accept some answers to your questions? 14% is a dismal acceptance rating no matter the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    var answer=confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?");
if(answer){
    //ajax call here
    }
});
```

Just add your own alert/dialogue code to the function.

Comment: Yes, but this will execute even if it is still in my site.

Comment: @Nikolay, if he closes the window or tab then he is not on ANY site!

Comment: Note that this is the "right" way to do it and is a lot better: `window.onbeforeunload=function(){return 'Are you sure you want to leave? PLZ STAY!!!'}` which would, when they try to leave the page, ask them if they are sure.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function unload() {
      alert('window closed');
  }
window.onunload = unload;
</script>
```